# Magento 2: display recently viewed product on product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, recently-viewed

I want to display recently viewed products on the product detail page with slider.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below guide which will help you.

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-magento-2-recently-viewed-products.html

or you can also do my xml layout to do this

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` for testing purpose

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
    <action method="setPageSize">
       <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
    </action>
  </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can add above snippet to `catalog_product_view.xml` file of your custom theme.